# qt5 error occur Poppler::Document* document

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, poppler

I'm making PDF viewer using qt and poppler library but, the error occurred running this program

> error was ***'The program has unexpectedly finished.***'
>  error
>   occur  Poppler::Document* document =
>   Poppler::Document::load(filename);

When I erase **Poppler::Document::load(filename)** error not occurred

How to solve it?

I found an error code below but follow this example [poppler Qt5](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QUrl>
#include <poppler-qt5.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/home/googolhkl/사진/IMG_20150925_1.jpg");
    cv::imshow("display",image);

    QString filename;
    Poppler::Document* document = Poppler::Document::load(filename);
    if (!document || document->isLocked()) {
      // ... error message ....
      delete document;
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load existing file, but in your example the file name is empty:

```
QString filename;
```

Comment: thank you for answer. i solved this problem . problem reason was library problem.